# Quais são as fases de padronização de uma propriedade CSS?

Tags: css

Às vezes pesquiso no site [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com) a compatibilidade entre navegadores de algumas propriedades CSS e me deparo com algumas siglas, tal como: `LS`, `WD`, `ED`, `CR` etc., como por exemplo, a propriedade `clip-path` me mostra a sigla `CR`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz uma pesquisa e vi que `CR` significa *Candidate Recommendation*. Ao que me pareceu, a propriedade ainda não foi padronizada, seria uma *candidata para tal*. Sei que uma propriedade é padronizada quando possui a sigla LS (*Living Standard*).

Quais as etapas que uma propriedade tem que passar até chegar ao `LS`? E porquê ela pode, fatalmente, não chegar nem ao `LS`?

Comment: O assunto é interessante, e um mais profundo do que parece... Vamos ver se o Maujor aparece para responder essa :)

Comment: Quem seria o Maujor?

Comment: Se vc é o Tio, e o Leo o Vovô, o Maujor é o Dinossauro  do CSS! Aqui está o site dele https://www.maujor.com/ ele tem uma história de vida bem interessante tem, vários livros publicados, da palestras etc..., inclusive vc pode ver no Youtube alguns vídeos sobre esse mito do mundo dev. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/13752/maujor

Comment: @hugocsl achei que vc podia me quebrar essa. Acho meio confuso essa siglas. Bom, mas se o Maujor puder me esclarecer essa questão vou ficar mt agradecido.

Comment: Sam eu até separei um material, mas estou sem tempo para fazer uma resposta no nível que eu gostaria, e tem algumas coisas que tb não consegui identificar, como por ex. "quando ocorre a mudança de status", acho que isso é uma decisão particular do comitê dependendo da disponibilidade dos membros avaliarem... não consegui infos quanto a isso... Se vc achar que uma reposta um pouco mais simplificada pode ter algum valor posso contribuir com o que tenho em mãos aqui

Comment: @hugocsl Eu tô fazendo umas pesquisas... se eu conseguir algo, eu mesmo vou postar uma resposta rs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Vou tentar não me alongar na resposta. E vou citar todos os links com informações complementares e detalhadas. Inclusive sobre o status geral do CSS*

Essa lista indica a maturidade das especificações dos códigos na **W3C**. Indo da menos estável até a mais estável.

*Fonte:* https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma propriedade pode passar por várias revisões dentro de uma mesma "categoria" antes que mude para um status mais estável.

Esse é o histórico de revisões do código `Media Query`. Repare que por muito tempo eme foi um `CR` antes de realmente virar um `REC`.

*Fonte:* https://www.w3.org/standards/history/css3-mediaqueries

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acredito que a demora nas atualizações dos padrões antigamente se davam principalmente pq o `Comitê W3C` se comunicava por uma lista de e-mail. Acredite se quiser, eles não tinha um repositório e era tudo acordado e discutido por uma lista de e-mail!

Aqui tem um exemplo de como eram essas conversar.

Lista com histórico: https://www.w3.org/Style/2012/MediaQueriesDisposalOfComments.html

Um exemplo de como eram as conversas: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2012Mar/0409.html

Então o comum era que para cada "nova propriedade" fosse criada uma lista de e-mail, e que quisesse contribuir com o Comitê entrava na lista e participava da criação das especificações etc... Aqui tem uma lista de como é organizados os padrões CSS estabelecidos pela **W3C**, e inclusive vc consegue ver o histórico de cada *specs*.

Veja: https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/specs.en.html

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

### E como é o CSS hoje? E o CSS4?

Bom, hoje as coisas evoluíram um pouco, e os projetos da **W3C** estão no `GitHub`, isso facilita para acompanhar o desenvolvimento das coisas e para os entusiastas que querem contribuir de alguma forma.

Esse é o `GitHub` da **W3C** https://github.com/w3c/ e esse é o projeto do **Working Group dos Drafs do CSS** https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts

***Aqui é uma opinião minha:*** É muito provável que o **CSS4** nunca vá existir... Na verdade o CSS ao meu ver é um eterno Beta. Algumas propriedade vão evoluindo enquanto outras serão "deprecadas". Além disso, os módulos de propriedades do CSS estão em níveis diferentes, uns mais avançados e outros menos, e mesmo no que se diz "CSS 3" existem módulos que ainda são 1 e outros que já são 4...

Por exemplos:

- [`Grid Layout` ainda especificado como `CR` **Level 1**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/CR-css-grid-1-20171214/)
- [Mas o `Grid Layout` **Level 2** já está como `WD`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-2/)
- [Já o `Medias Query` por sua vez estão no **Level 4** `CR`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/CR-mediaqueries-4-20170905/)

Isso me leva a crer que nunca será lançado um **CSS 4**... O que vai ocorrer é apenas um evolução constante e gradual (*evergreen*). Como a Adobe faz por exemplo com o Photoshop, onde atualmente não tem mais a versão 9 ou 10, agora é apenas a "versão atual" :)

Aqui tem um artigo bem interessante quanto ao futuro e o **CSS4:**
 https://www.silocreativo.com/en/css4-the-new-version-of-css-that-will-never-exist/

Esse é o status atual de todas as propriedades
 https://www.w3.org/standards/techs/css#w3c_all

---

### Importante

É preciso ter em mente que ninguém, nem nenhum Browser, é de fato "obrigado" a seguir o que determina a **W3C**. Por isso é comum vermos até hoje propriedades como os *Vendor Prefix*, como `-moz-` e `-webkit-`, normalmente essas são propriedades não "oficiais", não são especificadas pela W3C e podem funcionar exclusivamente em um browser ou outro, ou mesmo nem existir em outros browsers. Além disso, cada browser tem certa liberdade para tratar a estilização de certos campos, como os `<button>` ou `<select>`, que normalmente têm estilos de `user-agent` diferentes de browser para browser.

Aqui por exemplo está a lista das especificações e de como elas estão no browser da Mozilla FireFox
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS3