# Como funciona e como usar a propriedade aspect-ratio?

Tags: css

Eu não sei como funciona essa propriedade e nem como usá-la pois já tentei pesquisar mais sobre ela e só achei dois sites que menciona um pouco sobre ela:

[CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/designing-an-aspect-ratio-unit-for-css/)

[smashing magazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/03/aspect-ratio-unit-css/)

Mas na prática visualmente não alterá em nada já tentei os mesmo códigos *CSS* dos dois sites, mas é a mesma coisa de não ter efeito algum:

```html
<style>
  .box {
      width: 400px;
      height: auto;
      background: red;
      aspect-ratio: 1/1; /* ou 16/9 */
   }
</style>

<div class="box"></div>
```

Minhas perguntas são:

**Como funciona e como usar essa propriedade?**

**Ela é suportada em todos os navegadores?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como vc pode consultar aqui https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_aspect-ratio nenhum browser tem suporte a essa propriedade, então logicamente não tem como testar e dizer ***como funciona*** e o máximo que se pode ter é o que diz o `draft`, e sendo um `draft` pode mudar a qualquer momento e essa resposta já não valeria de mais nada... https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-4/#ratios

Então, mesmo que se explique como funciona "deveria funcionar", nada garante que de fato funcionará assim. Se vc quiser ler mais sobre o Status do CSS vc pode ver algumas dicas aqui [Quais são as fases de padronização de uma propriedade CSS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/354803/quais-s%c3%a3o-as-fases-de-padroniza%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-uma-propriedade-css)

Suporte atual dos browser para a propriedade `aspect-ratio`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Porque existe uma propriedade que não pode ser utilizada?

Comment: @GabrielOliveira pq ela ainda não é oficial, e dependendo do Status que ela está no Draft pode ainda simplesmente nunca ver a luz do dia e nunca ser oficializada... Aqui vc pode entender melhor como as propriedades CSS são "criadas" e oficializadas ou não pela W3C https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/354803/quais-s%c3%a3o-as-fases-de-padroniza%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-uma-propriedade-css/355543#355543

Comment: @GabrielOliveira não é a W3 que implementa nos navegadores, eles apenas dizem as "normas" e formatos que deverão usar e o efeito que deve produzir, a responsabilidade de tornar isto em parte do navegador é de cada desenvolvedores de navegadores especificos, o Firefox é um o Chrome é outro, o motor do firefox é um, do Chrome é outro, o mesmo vale para Edge e Safari, a responsabilidade de aplicar recursos descritos e torna-los em realidade é das "empresas" ou organizações open-source, a w3 é apenas quem "dita". Logo não tem como um propriedade existir no mesmo momento que ela é idealizada.

Comment: Gabriel, claro que o navegador pode até implementar algo que não faz parte das normas/padrões, mas isto é chamado de não-padrão (non-standard), logo isso provavelmente não vai existir em 2 navegadores diferentes, tem muitos exemplos de funcionalidades que são apenas do Firefox e outras apenas do Chrome, são as vezes úteis, mas não tem como depender delas para algo cross-browser. PS: Hugo +1 por informar que isto ainda é um rascunho/ideia e que ainda não foi realmente "aprovada".

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento bem observado até, realmente a implantação no final das contas vai do time que desenvolve o browser. Um exemplo bem doido é o `-webkit-text-stroke` que é uma propriedade relativamente antiga, que não é oficial, e que para funcionar em qualquer browser, Safari, Chrome, FireFox e até no Edge antigo precisa usar o vendo prefix `-webkit-` https://caniuse.com/#feat=text-stroke Ao passo que outras coisas já deprecadas pela própria W3C ainda funcionam nos browsers modernos :D

Comment: Note que se isto sair do draft (rascunho/ideia) e se tornar uma norma e passar a ser suportado por um navegador, eu recomendo que você edite a resposta mas mantenha a informação que hoje existe como histórico, se possivel com datas nos titulos para explicar as motivações daquilo ter sido escrito em tal "tempo"  e assim ajudaria a notar a evolução desta propriedade CSS. Imagine q a propriedade exista no futuro, mas tenha mudado algo, seria interessante passar isso. Mas claro ao menos para mim que gosto de saber a história por trás das tecnologias

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento com certeza, edições com datas e mantendo o histórico é sempre legal, pelo menos ao meu ver... As vezes costumo voltar em resposta e atualizar informações quando necessário, mas se for depender da W3C soltar alguma atualização podemos esperar sentados.....